# I want to access variable of function in different function of same class

Tags: java

i want to access ssc in all the functions like open() and bind() as well

```
public void createSocket()
{
    ServerSocketChannel ssc = null;
}    
public void openSocket() throws IOException
{
    ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
}    
public void bind()    
{
    ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8888));
    ssc.configureBlocking(false);
}`
```

Comment: @Odedra Whatever for? It has been answered, and there's really no need for more of this stuff.

Comment: I think the solution is to read your instructional text. This is such a basic development tenet that the concern is you have spent zero time learning and instead will come here to ask every basic question during your 'learning' experience.

Answer (score 1):

Since `scc` is declared as a local variable it cannot be access in other methods. It needs to be declared at the class level.

```
public OuterClass {
    private ServerSocketChannel ssc = null; << Class level declaration

    public void createSocket()
    {
        ssc = null;
    }    

    public void openSocket() throws IOException
    {
        ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    }    

    public void bind()    
    {
        ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8888));
        ssc.configureBlocking(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define it as a global variable not local to `createSocket()` you will only be able to use it in the `createSocket()` scope the way you have it defined now.  You need to make it a `class` level variable.

Answer (score 0):

So define it in the class scope where these methods are defined. For example:

```
public class MySocketClass {

   private ServerSocketChannel ssc;

   public void createSocket() {
      // this method now seems redundant; consider replacing this functionality
      // in the default constructor for this class
      ssc = null;
   }

    public void openSocket() throws IOException {
        ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    }

    public void bind() {
        ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8888));
        ssc.configureBlocking(false);
    }
}
```

And then you can reference them such as:

```
MySocketClass msc = new MySocketClass();
msc.openSocket();
msc.bind();
```